# Prove that each point in the set $\{x_n: d(a,x_0)<1, d(x_{n+1},a)<\frac{1}{2}d(x_n,a)\}$ is an isolated point.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Prove that each point in the set $\{x_n: d(a,x_0)<1, d(x_{n+1},a)<\frac{1}{2}d(x_n,a)\}$ is an isolated point.

I know that this is meant to be really simple, but I'm really struggling. I just can't find $\epsilon$ such that $B(x_n, \epsilon$) doesn't contain any $x_m$, where $m\ne n$.

Comment: It might help to write out the definition of an isolated point.

Comment: Your definition of the set is not valid. You should start with a sequence $(x_n)_n$ having special properties, and then define $A:=\{x_n\mid n=0,1,\dots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$x_0$ is an isolated point since $B(x_0, \epsilon)$ doesn't contain any $x_m$ where $m\neq 0$ for any $\epsilon < \frac{d(a,x_0)}{2},$

Similarly $x_1$ is an isolated point for any $\epsilon < \min\{\frac{d(a,x_1)}{2},d(x_1,x_0)\}.$